# Entering grid in cross type layout using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, print-composer

I'm trying to put the map's grid in a cross style but I've tried several things and I can't find how to put GridStyle.Cross in case it's like that

```
map.grid().setFrameStyle(QgsLayoutItemMapGrid.ExteriorTicks) 
map.grid().setUnits(QgsLayoutItemMapGrid.DynamicPageSizeBased)
map.grid().setIntervalX(60) 
map.grid().setIntervalY(60) 
map.grid().setCrs(QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem.fromEpsgId(4326))
map.grid().setGridLineWidth(0.2) 
map.grid().setGridLineColor(QColor(74, 74, 74))
map.grid().setAnnotationFontColor(QColor(0, 0, 0))
map.grid().setBlendMode(QPainter.CompositionMode_SourceOver)
map.grid().setFrameWidth(2)
map.grid().setFramePenSize(1)
map.grid().setFramePenColor(QColor(0, 0, 0))
map.grid().setFrameFillColor1(QColor(0, 0, 0))
map.grid().setFrameFillColor2(QColor(255, 255, 255))
map.grid().setEnabled(True)
map.grid().setAnnotationEnabled(True)
```

Comment: What do you mean by a cross style? Can you share an example?

Comment: I think you need to add some preceding code before this will qualify as a code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

Aquí una captura de la Api de Qgis

[image]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

map.grid.setStyle(QgsLayoutItemMapGrid.FrameAnnotationsOnly)
map.grid.setStyle(QgsLayoutItemMapGrid.Cross)
map.grid.setStyle(QgsLayoutItemMapGrid.Markers)

Al menos eso me ayudo para poder definir cual diseño .

Comment: Welcome to GIS Stack Exchange. This is an English language site, please explain your answer clearly in English.